# How to extend link field type in D8?

Tags: entities, 8, navigation

It's good to see the Link field type in D8. It takes a URL and (optionally) link text.

I'm adding a multiple links field to a content type and would like users to be able to provide some styling clues as well: e.g. this link is the primary one, this one needs a download icon. Basically let the user add CSS classes to each of the links in the same way they can add urls, text to each link they enter.

Is there a way to adding a new part to the field type?

(EDIT: I've put the answer into a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/artfulrobot/2687501))

Comment: Just create new field formatter plugin and extend the \Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\LinkFormatter

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The field formatter seems the third thing I'd need to create. First I need somewhere to store the classes data, then I need a widget enabling user to specify classes, then I need a formatter to apply them to the HTML.

Comment: I think the formatter is a good idea, but it probably doesn't fit @artfulrobot's use case of having users save arbitrary styling clues for link data. You can extend the link class and give it a different annotation and change the schema method (similar to Drupal 7). This creates a new field type plugin. File and Image field type plugins work similarly. This won't do anything about your current data though and you'll need to migrate.

Comment: So there's not a sort of "alter" option where I can alter an existing field (link) to add the extra part?

Comment: No, there is no field schema alter hook in either Drupal 7 or Drupal 8.  Edit: Actually, I guess you could alter the plugin definition, provided your own class, implement schema method, and then all link fields will have that schema from then on. This seems like a lot of behavior to change for something like a custom menu system.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. So I need to make a new field type, or use [field_group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to group a link and a text/select field for the classes.

Comment: I meant [field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mean field widget in my first comment :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check \Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldType\LinkItem, you see that it supports an array of options.

LinkFormatter then passes those to the URL.

So the only thing that you need is a custom widget that allows you to select/configure classes within the options somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the use case of users saving arbitrary class/style data with the link content when it's created. This would be for a site builder to configure all link field content for a specific link field to have that style/class data.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point. the link field can store any classes. It's just a question of how you expose it in the UI, you could make a textfield so anything is allowed or you could make a select/checkboxes to only allow specific classes. It was explicitly decided to offer the storage but not provide any advanced widgets and leave that to contrib/custom modules.

Comment: Check out my [Segue - classy links module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/artfulrobot/2687501) (sandbox) that does as you suggest :-)